# How prometheus consul service discovery works if ACL is enabled?

Tags: prometheus, acl, consul

I have a few services registered with Consul, I have to monitor the services registered with Consul using Prometheus.

Prometheus provides [consul_sd_config](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#consul_sd_config) for service discovery, but I have ACL enabled in consul for security, and a token is required to use consul catalog API, how does Prometheus address these issues?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what's unclear. It's all described in the link you provided :)

1. you create ACL allowing reading the registered services
2. take the ACL token and put it together with other information to Prometheus configuration - everything described in https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#consul_sd_config

```
# The information to access the Consul API. It is to be defined
# as the Consul documentation requires.
[ server: <host> | default = "localhost:8500" ]
[ token: <secret> ]
[ datacenter: <string> ]
[ scheme: <string> | default = "http" ]
[ username: <string> ]
[ password: <secret> ]
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, my token is generated by ACL in the runtime, how do I populate it here in the YML file?

Comment: I'm you mean by 'runtime'. ACLs are created explicitly via GUI or API. In GUI you can go to ACL tab to see list of ACLs. You locate your ACL, click on its name and there you can see your token.

Have you read this guide?: https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/consul/access-control-setup-production

Comment: Sorry for not being descriptive. I am dealing with an application with microservice architecture, consul and Prometheus are microservices, which are containerized using docker. I have API's exposed in consul for Read access token. I presume I have to use that token in prometheus.yml, but that token is generated dynamically by consul, how do I use it here? P.S Tech stack I use is Node.js